# Realise an auto link to target website title function

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I want to implement a function, which gets the target html  of a website and converts the given link and the `<title>` to a html link.

**The Code:**

```
<?php
function get_title($url){
  $str = file_get_contents($url);
  if(strlen($str)>0){
    $str = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str)); // supports line breaks inside <title>
    preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/i",$str,$title); // ignore case
    return $title[1];
  }
}
//Example:
echo get_title("http://www.washingtontimes.com/");
?>
```

**The problem:**
This process needs time. Imagine, there is a page with 5-20 links.

**The solution:** I want to convert all urls and save them as html links, so my website won't load too long.

Should I do it like this ? I know, it's better to store raw data in a database, but I can't see another solution...

Greets

Comment: Does this not work? A parser would be safer..

Comment: Your question is a bit broad, but on the surface it looks fine. What are your issues with it?

Comment: when you run this function on page load the DOM will load very long, so I want to know, If I should do that before I save my data in my database!